# Heroku deployment vite not found

Tags: heroku, vite

I have tried `"start": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false vite preview",` but this does not seem to work still getting the same error. `sh: 1: vite: not found`

Comment: If Vite is already installed, it's possible that the npm script you're using to start the server is configured incorrectly. Double-check the command you're using in your `package.json` file to ensure that it references the correct binary path for Vite. You could try `./node_modules/vite/bin/vite preview` instead

Answer (score 0):

This problem tortured me for about an hour before I stopped overthinking it. In your package.json, you'll see that "vite" is inside your devDependencies. I moved that up into my "dependencies" and it cleared that error and gave me another: " Cannot find package '@vitejs/plugin-react'". So I also moved that package from my devDependencies into my dependencies and voila! I ran a successful build. Hope this helps you out. I was pulling my hair out scouring Google before I just tried the simplest answer...